# '\' backslash in single quotes giving unpredictable output in shell script linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

the output for the following two commands are same:

```
echo 'my\name' | grep 'my\\name'
my\name
```

and also the output for the next command is also same,

```
echo 'my\name' | grep 'my\\\name'
my\name
```

Can anyone pls guide why it is resulting in the same output??
Why an extra backslash also not affecting any change in the output?

however, if we increase the number of backslash to four in grep then the output goes away,

```
echo 'my\name' | grep 'my\\\\name'
```

no output

Pls guide me with the behavior of grep and backslash in single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of a backslash in a regular expression (such as in grep) is different to how a shell might interpret it.  A shell might look at `\n` and without quotes, convert to a carriage return.  In a regular expression a `\` means "do not interpret the next character as special regex character, treat it as a literal character".

In this example

```
'my\\\name'
```

You are saying:

Find "my" followed by a literal "\" (the `\\`), followed by a literal "n" (the `\n`).

So this matched `my\name`

The next example:

```
'my\\\\name'
```

You are saying:

Find "my" followed by a literal "\" (the `\\`), followed by another literal "\" (the `\\`).

So this does not match `my\name`.

Comment: suppose if we use double quotes instead of single quotes then how the behavior would vary?

Comment: If you use double quotes, you are letting the shell interpret the string first, which would make the `\n` turn into a carriage return.

Comment: if we use double quotes in case of regex pattern, then can u pls read the behavior?

Comment: @Paul - A small qualification: `sh` interprets `\n` as new-line, but `bash` doesn't, so the single- and double-quote expansions are identical in the above examples. To create a literal new-line `bash` uses `$'\n'`, though for some reason (possibly a bug) this doesn't work within double quotes on Ubuntu 15.04, though all other `$` expansions work as expected.

Comment: With examples; `'my\name'` doesnt match (in grep) with that you echoed. Because `echo` without `-e` it thinks that you write it in string and grep look for `my<newline>ame`. Also try it with this 2 commands. `echo 'my\name'|grep 'my\\.ame'` and `echo 'my\name'|grep 'my\\\.name'`. As @Paul said; `\` the backslash has special mean and also `.` dot. With 2 backslashes it will match. But not for 3. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: @Paul- What is the behavior of \ in double quotes as interpreted by shell and by regex?, can u pls highlight a brief over this?